# NoMethodError: undefined method `application' for Ckeditor::Rails:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling when it comes to compile the assets of my rails app to get it on Heroku. After
      rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace
I'm expecting this issue

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `application' for Ckeditor::Rails:Module
```

that I don't know to solve. The top part of the trace is returning this:

```
              (in /Users/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/ckeditor-4.1.0/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/init.js.erb)
            /Users/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/ckeditor-4.1.0/lib/ckeditor.rb:97:in `base_path'
            /Users/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/ckeditor-4.1.0/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/init.js.erb:6:in `block in singleton class'
            /Users/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/ckeditor-4.1.0/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/init.js.erb:-5:in `instance_eval'
            /Users/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/ckeditor-4.1.0/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/init.js.erb:-5:in `singleton class'
            /Users/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/ckeditor-4.1.0/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/init.js.erb:-7:in `__tilt_2156289000'
            /Users/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:170:in `call'
            /Users/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:170:in `evaluate'
            /Users/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
```

I have tried to look for that .init.js.erb file but I have not found it in my assets. Also I removed //= require ckeditor/init from my **assets/javascript/application.js**, which looks like this

```
            //= require jquery
            //= require jquery_ujs
            //= require ckeditor-jquery
            //= require turbolinks
            //= require the_comments
            //= require rich/base
```

In development seems to be working fine, any ideas what could I try?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ckeditor_rails gem with master version

```
gem 'ckeditor_rails', github: 'tsechingho/ckeditor-rails'
```